# Selectize.js destroy() method changes select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm using selectize.js in my project. What I need to do is clone part of the form (with selectized elements) and append it to the end of the form.

I've decided to destroy selectized elements before cloning, and after appending new subform initialize selectize again.

Here is a code for destroying selectized elements:

```
  var selectElements = $(plusButtonElement).parents(".subform_wrapper").first().find("> .subform_fields_wrapper").find("select");
$.each(selectElements, function(index, element){
    console.log(element);
    console.log($(element).val());    //Here we got value "10"
    $(element)[0].selectize.destroy();
    console.log($(element).val());    //Here we got value "A6"
});
```

It works - elements transform to the regular selects, BUT value of the select elements are changing. Did anyone face with this problem?

I checked selectize.js source and the only thing I can say is that value is changed in this code:

```
    self.$input
            .html('')
            .append(revertSettings.$children)
            .removeAttr('tabindex')
            .removeClass('selectized')
            .attr({tabindex: revertSettings.tabindex})
            .show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Tamara yes I think this is a bug of the Selectize.js.

I alter the following destroy method in selectize.js

```
destroy: function() {
        var self = this;
        var selectedValue = self.$input.val();
        var eventNS = self.eventNS;
        var revertSettings = self.revertSettings;

        self.trigger('destroy');
        self.off();
        self.$wrapper.remove();
        self.$dropdown.remove();

        self.$input
            .html('')
            .append(revertSettings.$children)
            .removeAttr('tabindex')
            .removeClass('selectized')
            .attr({tabindex: revertSettings.tabindex})
            .show();

        self.$control_input.removeData('grow');
        self.$input.removeData('selectize');

        $(window).off(eventNS);
        $(document).off(eventNS);
        $(document.body).off(eventNS);

        delete self.$input[0].selectize;

        self.$input.val(selectedValue);
    },
```

Here you can download my [selectize.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz68MzSx6HM5bXlZdnpuN2RyOEk/view?usp=sharing) file.